# Call from JS , does it reach the php file?

Tags: javascript, php

i am a newbie in JS/PHP, currently coding by looking up code/learning.
i am trying to call a php file (for doing stuff on the DB) from a JS.
Code below

```
var app=angular.module('loginapp',[]);
app.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$window){

$scope.doLogin = function() {

$http.post("http://localhost/search.php",'username':$scope.username,'password':$scope.password})

.success(function(response){
            var result = response.status;
            alert (result);
```

1) result is turning out to be undefined even if i hardcode the response inside php
2) how can i trace whether the call indeed reached the php file ? Console logs turn only if i directly run the php file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that code runs? You have syntax errors in it.

Comment: If you're using a browser to run your tests (not sure that you are) dev tools in FF/Chrome will show you **Request** and **Response** headers/values/etc. With that, you can see if the `post` failed, and what the request/response was (if any). Can you show your `search.php` file as well?

Comment: unless angular is now a javascript runtime, your string concats are wrong.